# Transforming from abc reference frame to the qd0 variable reference frame?

Tags: electric-machine, simulink, variable

I have been working on transforming variables from the abc reference frame to different qd0 frames of reference, such as the stationary reference frame, the synchronous reference frame, and the variable speed reference frame. I have been successful in getting the correct transformations for the fixed (ω=0) and synchronous (ω=377) qd0 frames, but I cannot obtain a correct transform for the variable speed frame. 
I am using the following ramp function:
[image: ω variable speed reference frame]

To transform between reference frames, I am using the following:
[image: Transform from one frame to another]

The results I am obtaining are:
[image]

and the result I am expecting is (yellow output above is supposed to match this):
[image]

I believe discrepancy is due to not having the correct θx while going from reference frame to reference frame, as right now I have θx set to 0 for all cases of ω. **How do I know what to set θx to?**

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct angle for a dq0 transformation to work. This is true for static velocity, constant velocity and variable velocity.

you say you have it working for constant velocity but not for variable does hint that you have not fully solved it for constant velocity since once you have the updated angle associated with constant velocity you actually have the solution for variable velocity.

What is velocity?  The rate of change of angle.
\$\omega = \dot\theta \$

so at zero velocity the angular position is static at some predetermined constant, the constant of integration.

At constant velocity, the change of angle is a constant slope.

Thus \$ \theta = \int \omega \Delta t \$.

In short... find the integration block in simulink \$\frac{1}{s}\$ block with the input being velocity and the output being angle.